# Redirect the ouput of an interactive command to file and terminal

Tags: bash, redirect, stdin

I have a program that requires user input, which I save to a file by using `tee`:

```
tee program.in | program
```

I also have to capture stdout and stderr in another file. This does the trick

```
tee program.in | program > program.out 2>&1
```

The problem is that the user input is going to be based on what the program outputted before, so the user has to see the programs output in the terminal.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, more idiomatic `tee` :-?,  i.e.

```
tee program.in | program 2>&1 | tee program.out
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. While the output gets written in the file, it doesn't get printed in the terminal. I could open the terminal and do a `tail -f program.out`, but the output is buffered, and does not appear right away.

Comment: if the output is buffered, then `tee` will delay in displaying it too. Try wrapping `program` with `unbuffer` (if it available on your system). Good luck.

Comment: Another solution (I found this while going through the Stack Overflow archives) is to wrap everything with `script`. Something like this `script -c "tee grid09.in | grid09" -f grid09.out` gets the job done.

Comment: ohhh. that's what you're doing. Ok, for future questions, a quick summary of your use case will help get a faster answer. Good luck and thanks for the chk mark.